# Eureka Server - Client setup - UnknownHostException - Could not get Swagegr definition from API

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, service-discovery

I am having simple setup - eureka server and 'event-catalog' as eureka client. Both hosted in AWS.
eureka server loads up the service on home page:

`EVENT-CATALOG    n/a (1) (1) UP (1) - cff2a33fcf77:event-catalog:8550`

However while accessing swagger-ui.html getting below errors on cloudwatch console :

```
2021-09-07 21:08:28.318 ERROR 42 --- [   scheduling-1] c.e.s.e.c.s.ServiceDescriptionUpdater    : Error while getting service definition for service : event-catalog Error : I/O error on GET request for "http://cff2a33fcf77:8550/v2/api-docs": cff2a33fcf77; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: cff2a33fcf77

ERROR 42 --- [   scheduling-1] c.e.s.e.c.s.ServiceDescriptionUpdater    : Skipping service id : event-catalog Error : Could not get Swagegr definition from API
```

My design and code is aligned with https://dzone.com/articles/centralized-documentation-in-microservice-spring-b

My eureka server configuration as below:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableScheduling
public class EurekaserverApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaserverApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

client (event-catalog) configuration as below

```
Annotated application class with '@EnableEurekaClient'
and application.yml config file has below configuration: 
---
spring:
  config.activate.on-profile: dev
eureka:
  instance:
    appname: event-catalog 
  client:
    enabled: true
    register-with-eureka: true
    #fetch-registry: false
    service-url:
      defaultZone: https://dev.eureka-service.rd.xxx.io/eureka/
```

Above whole setup works well when running locally. However after deploying to AWS it is giving above mentioned errors 'unknown host'. Wondering where it is getting 'cff2a33fcf77' and why not simply dev.event-catalog.rd.xxx.io/?

Please suggest what I am missing here. I am implementing discovery server first time and have spent so much time already to get it working. Please adivce.

Comment: What does eureka server /eureka/apps say?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out. I observed that spring cloud service instance was not resolving host correctly. It was taking AWS ecs task container id for the host.
Manipulated code to resolve host.